# CSS Background Position not shifting

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-sprites, background-position

this problem is a bit hard to explain.

I'm using a PNG sprite to do 48x48px icons and shifting the background by Class.

For example,

```
<style>

div.icon {
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background: url(../img/48sprite.png);
}

.cart { background-position: -96px -336px; }
.sale { background-position: -96px -384px; }
.bino { background-position: -96px -432px; }

</style>
```

(There are about 35 more of these background-position shifting classes for different icons.)

```
<div class="widelist">

<div class="widelist-itemwrap">

<div class="icon bino left"></div>

  <div class="widelist-content left">
    <h4>Widelist Heading</h4>
    <p>Widelist content</p>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

The problem is that no matter whether I put bino, sale, cart, or any of the other 36 icons in the sprite as the second class after the Icon class, I still just get the background image located at 0px, 0px of the PNG file.

The weird part is that it displays PERFECTLY in the Dreamweaver Design View, but as soon as I go to Live View or preview in Chrome/Safari etc, the icons all switch to the default icon instead of being shifted.

Developer Tools in Chrome shows that the background-position property has been properly shifted, but visually, the icon is incorrect.

Just to clarify, I've used this technique successfully many times before with no problem - just having a bad day I guess.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `div.icon` is [more specific](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than `.bino`.

The `background` rule is shorthand for (amongst others) the `background-position` property, so the `background` property on `div.icon` is preventing your differing `background-position` rules from being applied.

You can fix it by changing `div.icon` to just `.icon`.

Comment: +1 - so you have some points since you probably won't get this ticked. @Tobey - Accept thirtydot's answer if it worked for you. You should also change background to background-image if you are not planning to define any other properties in it.

Comment: @My Head Hurts: Thanks for that :)